# How to setup a Namecheap domain with 1and1 hosting and Cloudflare DNS

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, cloudflare, dns-servers

I have a domain with Namecheap and a hosting account with 1and1, and I want to use the Cloudflare DNS for free SSL.

How would I set up the DNS properly?

Comment: Sorry but you need a guide, not an answer.

Comment: @harvey It's very simple, just create an account in Cloudflare and add a website, it will walk you through the rest. In short, you only need to change the nameservers in Namecheap's domain control panel.